# Generate XSL-FO from Office OpenXML (DOCX)

Tags: openxml, docx, xsl-fo

I need to create XSL-FO from existing Docx file and then convert it to PDF file. I found the XSLT from `DOCX4J` project. I just want to know if I don't use `DOCX4J` at all, how can I apply the XSLT to DOCX file to produce XSL-FO file?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029603/xslt-xml-word-to-xsl-fo-pdf). From its answer, you probably need to follow the steps, obviously except the #4.

Comment: Thanks, I checked, that one only works for Word 2003.

Comment: First, you can't just apply an XSLT to a DOCX file. A DOCX file is a zip container with directory structure and XML files inside. This information is encapsulated in the WordML file format (that you get if ran Word and did a "Save As XML". SO, you would need code in the first place to unzip the file and then you could modify the XSLs referenced by @bytebuster to use document() to get access to the separate chunks of XML (like the styles.xml inside the zip). The XSLs referenced can easily be changed to work with WordML for > Word 2003, all that is needed is to change the namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can't readily use docx4j's XLST without using the rest of docx4j, since the XSLT relies heavily on Xalan extension functions which call docx4j's Java code.