# How to convert Word documents (XML based) to PDF, with C#?

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, ms-word, apache-fop

I have to do some automation of converting Word documents to PDF. By doing some research, I found that starting from Microsoft Office 2007, Word documents are XML based. Furthermore, I found that there is a free solution ApacheFOP doing conversion from XML to PDF, however, I still didn't manage to find the way to automate it with C#. There is nFOP (version that runs on the .NET framework), but some detailed explanation of implementing it, not really.

Comment: Microsoft Word XML is vastly different from the XML that ApacheFOP converts to PDF (xsl-fo). This question addresses the conversion of Word XML to xsl-fo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029603/xslt-xml-word-to-xsl-fo-pdf

Comment: In other words, if I want to use ApacheFOP, first I have to transform Word document into the XSL Formatting Objects (XSL-FO) format, and from there by using ApacheFOP I can convert it to PDF, right?

Comment: Yes. I haven't done this but it seems like a path worth trying.

Comment: Okay, let me give a try. Thank you Frank! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [docx4j.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j.NET/3.0.1)

That's a .NET version of docx4j, which is a Java library which converts docx to PDF using FOP.

See [ConvertOutPDF.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutPDF.java)

Before you go to the effort of downloading etc, you might want to use the [online demo](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/demo_landing.html) to see whether the PDF output is close to your needs.

**Disclosure: I lead the docx4j project. **

Comment: This is a solution worth noting, but using this demo site, PDF output doesn't satisfy my needs.

Comment: OK, well - assuming a large gap - you may as well forget about using FOP; the effort to get the output you want will be too much.  Instead, see whether LibreOffice/OpenOffice output is good enough for your needs.

Comment: Ok. What I found is PDFCreator, it's free and output PDF is actually very good. It seems worth trying. Are you maybe familiar with it?

Comment: If that's the virtual printer one, it depends on having Word (or OO/LO) installed, in which case query what you gain over the native PDF output support in Word/OO/LO.

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally got the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly solution would be to make a "save as" using microsoft office interop...

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

And find the related stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651880/save-open-xml-as-pdf)

Comment: Yes, but in order to use it, you need to have MS Office installed, I'm trying to go with some free solution.

Comment: I think a paid library is the way to go - or you could try to create your own library wrapping things around ITextSharp...

Comment: I found ITextSharp earlier, and it is free, however in order to use it within some commercial app, you have to publish your source code, therefore I kept searching.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one library that can convert XML to PDF in C#/.NET and vice versa known as **[Aspose.PDF for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/.net/pdf-component.aspx)** . I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Aspose.pdf is a very useful tool, however it is commercial, I'm going for some free solution.